# How to modify reference for multiple projects easily?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution, containing 20 projects, refer to the same assembly.  Now I change the path of the assembly, I must modify the reference path for each project one by o

Comment: Have a look at the project files, they're xml. Try a `Replace in Files`, should be reasonably easy. A backup first might be a good idea too.

Answer (score 0):

Do not refer the reference assembly directly, Instead you should put reference to some common location where this reference assembly is kept, then all projects should reference this assembly from common location instead of actual path of referenced assembly.

Doing this would have saved your time as original change in path of original assembly doesn't matter to all projects as they are referring common location.

So, whenever original path of referenced assembly is changed you just need to put the referenced assembly to common location.

Hope this will help!